# multiple Treeview align to left

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

My purpose is to create multiple Treeviews, from different dataframes(diferetn number of columns), each one store in each frame, and all of them in the main frame, in my code i can reach almost 100%, the only problem is i cant aligan the "smalls" dataframes or treeviews to left side, the result is like the pic ill attach, tried to use side="" (left,top,bottom) but cant align all to left, not in mid, any tips ples Thanks in advance

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import string
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
string.ascii_lowercase
n = 5
m = 25
cols11 = string.ascii_lowercase[:m]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, n,size=(n , m)), columns=list(cols11))
a = 5
b = 15
cols12 = string.ascii_lowercase[:b]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, a,size=(a , b)), columns=list(cols12))
c = 5
d= 10
cols22 = string.ascii_lowercase[:d]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, c,size=(c , d)), columns=list(cols22))
e = 5
f= 5
cols32 = string.ascii_lowercase[:f]
df3= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, e,size=(e , f)), columns=list(cols32))
cols = list(df.columns)
cols1 = list(df1.columns)
cols2 = list(df2.columns)
cols3 = list(df3.columns)

root1 = tk.Tk()
main_frame=tk.Frame(root1)
main_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH,expand=1)
my_canvas=tk.Canvas(main_frame)
my_canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT,fill=tk.BOTH,expand=1)
my_scrollbary=tk.Scrollbar(main_frame,orient=tk.VERTICAL,command=my_canvas.yview)
my_scrollbary.pack(side=tk.RIGHT,fill=tk.Y)
my_scrollbarx=tk.Scrollbar(root1,orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,command=my_canvas.xview)
my_scrollbarx.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM,fill=tk.X)
my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbary.set, xscrollcommand=my_scrollbarx.set)
my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e:my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all")))
root=tk.Frame(my_canvas)
my_canvas.create_window((0,0),window=root,anchor="nw")
frame1=tk.Frame(root)
frame1.pack(anchor='w')
tree = ttk.Treeview(frame1)
tree.pack()
tree["columns"] = cols
for i in cols:
    tree.column(i, anchor="w")
    tree.heading(i, text=i, anchor='w')
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    tree.insert("",0,text=index,values=list(row))

frame2=tk.Frame(root)
frame2.pack(anchor='w')
tree1 = ttk.Treeview(frame2)
tree1.pack()
tree1["columns"] = cols1
for i in cols1:
    tree1.column(i, anchor="w")
    tree1.heading(i, text=i, anchor='w')
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    tree1.insert("",0,text=index,values=list(row))

frame3=tk.Frame(root)
frame3.pack(anchor='w')
tree2 = ttk.Treeview(frame3)
tree2.pack()
tree2["columns"] = cols2
for i in cols2:
    tree2.column(i, anchor="w")
    tree2.heading(i, text=i, anchor='w')
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    tree2.insert("",0,text=index,values=list(row))
#
frame4=tk.Frame(root)
frame4.pack(anchor='w')
tree3 = ttk.Treeview(frame4)
tree3.pack()
tree3["columns"] = cols3
for i in cols3:
    tree3.column(i, anchor="w")
    tree3.heading(i, text=i, anchor='w')
for index, row in df3.iterrows():
    tree3.insert("",0,text=index,values=list(row))
root.mainloop()
```

UPDATE: thanks to @acw1668 comment code is working all is align to left

picture show result:

[image]

Comment: Your code isn't runnable as posted. Please [edit] the example so that we can run it.

Comment: thanks for cooment @BryanOakley looking for dumy data

Comment: Try adding `anchor='w'` to all `treeX.pack()`.

Comment: @acw1668 tried with anchor but still not working :(

Comment: @BryanOakley data added now its working :)

Comment: It should be adding `anchor='w'` to all `frameX.pack()` (parents of those treeviews) instead.

Comment: wow thanks @acw1668 fully working now, updating code thansk so much

Comment: Since the data doesn't affect the layout, the example would be better if it didn't depend on numpy and pandas. The example needs to be as small and lightweight as possible.

Comment: @BryanOakley the data was exactly like my real data (columsn,rows), but thanks for notice about example, ill keep that for future questions, thanks again

Comment: It is better to create an answer instead of updating the question.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @acw1668, adding `frame.pack(anchor='w')` to all parents of each frame, solve my problem

thanks again